# Starting p3dx using p2os

Tags: ros, p2os, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am following the tutorials in http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20p2os

I have only one laptop mounted on the robot (p3dx) hence i am not following the 7th and 8th section of the above mentioned tutorial.

When i run the

```
rosrun p2os_dashboard p2os_dashboard
```

i see the dashboard getting displayed but except the Rosout (in green) ui others are not colored (red/green) and the battery is 0% even though the robot is fully charged. I am not able to enable or disable the motors.
I see the problem is here itself.

And when i run the

```
rosrun p2os_drivers p2os
```

i get the following errors.

```
[ INFO] [1323459143.327099680]: using serial port: [/dev/ttyS0]
[ INFO] [1323459143.360479690]: P2OS connection opening serial port /dev/ttyS0...
[ERROR] [1323459143.360617485]: P2OS::Setup():tcgetattr():
[ERROR] [1323459143.360707540]: p2os setup failed...
```

I have given the read and write permissions to ttyS* and ttyUSB*.
I am able to use ROSARIA and get the robot moving using keyboard operations.
I am sure something is being missed. Pls let me know

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12294/starting-p3dx-using-p2os/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-13**:
Can anyone help me here. Got stuck at this point. Thanks

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-09**:
I am using ROS electric on ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok found the issue.
Had to remap the param name port to /dev/ttyUSB0
Its working now

Thanks,
Karthik

---

You may update the param at ./p2os_driver/include/p2os_driver/robot_params.h but beware that the sick laser usage might have a conflict at this port. You may have it as a param in the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-21**:
Hi Karthik,
I can connect my robot with laptop by using serial-usb cable. I'm trying to control robot using keyboard.
when i run $rosrun p2os_dashboard p2os_dashboard i get ImportError: No module named msg. Can you please help me out.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2013-11-05**:
I am not sure of it! Can you post it as a new question!

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-11-06**:
Thanks. i managed to get it done using rosAria